# According to Shi'a Islam, did Fatimah (daughter of Prophet Muhammad) die naturally, or was she killed?

Tags: shiism, islamic-basis, death, ahl-ul-bayt, fatima-zahra

Someone asked me why Fatimah passed away in just 90 days or less after her father passed away:

> How did she die... my friend said she died naturally but I said she died
>   due to an accident behind the door?

*I am looking for a Shi'ite perspective.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Shia View

She was injured when defending her husband Imam Ali --peace be upon him-- at the time that Abu Bakr and Umar were trying to force Imam to give the pledge of allegiance to Abu Bakr, and she was later martyred from that injury that also immediately killed the embryo in her womb:

> وَ قَدْ كَانَ قُنْفُذٌ ... ضَرَبَ فَاطِمَةَ ع بِالسَّوْطِ حِينَ
>   حَالَتْ بَيْنَهُ وَ بَيْنَ زَوْجِهَا وَ أَرْسَلَ إِلَيْهِ عُمَرُ إِنْ
>   حَالَتْ بَيْنَكَ وَ بَيْنَهُ فَاطِمَةُ فَاضْرِبْهَا فَأَلْجَأَهَا
>   قُنْفُذٌ ... إِلَى عِضَادَةِ بَابِ بَيْتِهَا وَ دَفَعَهَا فَكَسَرَ
>   ضِلْعَهَا مِنْ جَنْبِهَا فَأَلْقَتْ جَنِيناً مِنْ بَطْنِهَا فَلَمْ
>   تَزَلْ صَاحِبَةَ فِرَاشٍ حَتَّى مَاتَتْ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهَا مِنْ
>   ذَلِكَ شَهِيدَة
>
> source: كتاب سليم بن قيس الهلالي، ج‏2، ص: 588

Comment: another documents about that terrible injuries are here: Al-imamah va-al-khilafah page 160 "الامامة و الخلافة، ص ۱۶۰" and Al-millal va-al-nahl volume1 page 57 " الملل و النحل، ج ۱، ص ۵۷ " and Al-foraq bain Al-foraq page107 " اَلفرقُ بین الفرق، ص۱۰۷ "

Comment: @FatemehBaqeri, thanks for mentioning, you can also edit the answer above if you mind, by the way, the reason I used Soleim's book as reference is that it is the oldest and amongst the most approved history books for the very early history of Islam in Shia perspective. Thanks again.