# Why is location of the grave of Fatima not known?

Tags: shiism, fatima-zahra

Why is the tomb of Sayada Fatima Zahra(a.s.) hidden?

I know she asked Imam Ali(a.s.) to not show her tomb for some guys who have tyrannize and abuse Her and Her family.

What is the goal of not specifying her tomb?

Comment: your question is fundamental question in Islam history. i decide to ask this. and when i was typing it in last minutes , stack exchange similar detection algorithm show up and notified me your Q link. then i understand your question and mine is similar to question that i asked before link : http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7039/747 and listed in related question right side of your page... useful .. thanks

Comment: Salaam,happy the Eid al-Ghadir, which is known as Eid al-Akbar (the greatest Eid) in Islamic narrations, could be referred to as the greatest celebration (Eid) of all religions. 
For the result of the mission of all the messengers of Allah (SWT) became accomplished on this day. Ya Ali

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shiite scholars have suggested many reasons for this:

1. First of all it was the choice of Lady Fatima(a.s.) to have a clandestine and overnight funeral and that her grave whereabouts be kept from public knowledge. Only her husband Ali Ibn Abi Talib who buried her holy body and her children knew about her grave whereabouts and didn't disclose it to anyone as she had wished.
2. Another reason was that her enemies and people who usurped Fadak (a property of hers) would not be able to attend her grave later; She had dismissed legitimacy of Caliphs and disregarded them during her life.
3. That her graveyard wouldn't be exhumed by sworn enemies of Prophet's Holy Household.
4. As she had intended to awaken and enlighten people about the Caliphs' oppression of Imam Ali(a.s.) and herself, by keeping her grave whereabouts a secret she wanted to express her eternal displeasure at Caliphs who treated her and her family with cruelty. She wanted every Muslim to be prompted to wonder "why is Lady Fatima Zahraa's grave unknown?"

---

Reference (Persian):

- [www.andisheqom.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419032523/http://www.andisheqom.com:80/Files/faq.php?level=4&id=4299&urlId=858)

Comment: Thanks, very good indeed, "she wanted to express her eternal displeasure at Caliphs" is the key point, the Muslims who buried the door of her house and hurt her and the imam of era were not allowed to take part in the burial, and according to the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household whoever tease Fatimah has teased the holy prophet. If this unknown grave place was not as it is now then everyone could have denied all those terrible stories that happened at first days after the holy prophet passed a way.

Answer (score 0):

According to Al-Tabari, the Iranian historian, writing around 220 AH, after the Prophet (pbuh) passed away his youngest daughter Fatima

> came to Abu Bakr asking for her share of the inheritance of her father (pbuh); this was the land of Fadak and his share of the tribute of Khaybar.
>
> Abu Bakr replied, 'I have heard the Messenger of God say: 'Our property cannot be inherited and whatever we leave behind is alms; by God, I will not abandon a course which I saw the Messenger of God practicing, but will continue doing it accordingly.' Fatima shunned him and did not speak to him about it until she died six months later. Ali buried her at night and did not permit Abu Bakr to attend her burial.

The hadith mentioned by Abu Bakr is authenticated by the Sunni scholars, Muslim and al-Bukhari; but this is disputed by Shia scholars who point out that this is against the laws of inheritance in Islam. Moreover, the caliphate that was assumed by Abu Bakr was disputed by Fatimas's husband, Ali ibn Ali Talib; in the Shia traditions, they also point out that Fatima suffered a miscarriage when Umar raided their home after Ali refused to pledge allegiance; this seems ample enough reasons to not allow Umar to attend the funeral, and nor to find the grave to shine posthumous glory on the caliphate.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the place of Fatima, the daughter of Prophet Mohammad, not known?
Fatima ordered Ali to hide her grave and make her grave unmarked in order to leave evidence and proof of the oppression inflicted on her and to perpetuate her opposition and struggle against the usurpers and criminals. The Imam also buried him at night and hid the location of his grave.

Ref:http://ensani.ir/fa/article/58173/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B3-

Answer (score -4):

Why Fatima's grave was unmarked, we don't know.  Nothing authentic tells us the exact reasoning.

It was old Arab tradition to not mark graves with name and date of death.

Allaho alim.

Comment: Do more research.there are Rational reasons to support it.

Comment: Arab culture is the reason.  That's rationale.

Comment: This is completely without enough research, the tomb of many other women of that era are known.

Comment: we can not say that It was old Arab tradition to not mark graves with name and date of death because the grave of Caliphates or prophet Mohammad's wives is not unknown.